# Complicated SQL query request

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
Number    Letter    KeyLetter

1         a         1
1         b         0
1         c         0
1         d         0

2         e         0
2         f         0
2         g         0

3         h         1
3         i         1
3         j         0
```

From it I want this:

```
Number    Letter    KeyLetter

1         a         1

2         e         0
2         f         0
2         g         0

3         h         1
3         i         1
```

For each set of numbers, if a letter is a KeyLetter, I want to ignore any non KeyLetters.
If a set of numbers doesn't have an entry where the letter is a KeyLetter, then show all of the entries in that set of numbers.

What SQL query would be able to do this?

Comment: Please tag your dbms (sql server, oracle, mysql etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, return the rows with KeyLetter = 1, and also those with a Number not having a KeyLetter = 1.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where t1.KeyLetter = 1
   or not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t1.Number = t2.Number
                    and t2.KeyLetter = 1)
```

Alternatively:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select Number, max(KeyLetter) maxKeyLetter
      from tablename
      group by Number) t2
  on t1.Number = t2.Number and t1.KeyLetter = t2.maxKeyLetter
```

Or...

```
select *
from tablename
where (Number, KeyLetter) in 
    (select Number, max(KeyLetter)
     from tablename
     group by Number)
```

The first two are Core ANSI SQL compliant. The latter one uses extension F641, "Row and table constructors".